# Create simple strong password-strength using RegEx in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can't use regex to create a strong pattern. Actually, because of the way I created my code I don't know how the function will fit in the middle of my code.

Note that the signup page is working perfectly if I remove lines 32 to 35 and change the inequal if statement but with weak password I really want that pattern because my backend expects a strong password.

signup react.js page ;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { signup } from '../actions/auth';
import './Signup.css';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { setAlert } from '../actions/alert';
import PasswordStrengthMeter from '../components/PasswordStrengthMeter';
import WelcomePageFooter from '../components/WelcomePageFooter';

function Signup({setAlert, signup, isAuthenticated }) {

  const [ strongpassword, setStrongpassword ] = useState('s');

  const [accountCreated, setAccountCreated] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    re_password: ''
  });

  const { name, email, password, re_password } = formData;
  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (password !== re_password)
            setAlert('Passwords do not match', 'error');

    var pattern = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$";

    if (password === re_password && password !== pattern )
      setAlert('Weak Password, please try again', 'error');

    if (password === re_password && password === pattern ) {
      signup (name, email, password, re_password);
      setAccountCreated(true);
    }
  };
 
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to='/' />
  }
  if (accountCreated) {
    return <Navigate to='/login' />
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='login'>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Diploman - Sign Up</title>
          <meta 
            name='description'
            content='sign up page'
          />
        </Helmet>
        <h1 className='signup__title'>Sign Up</h1>
        <p className='signup__lead'>Create your Account</p>
        <form className='signup__form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <div className='signup__form__group'>
            <input
              className='signup__form__input'
              type='text'
              placeholder='Name *'
              name='name'
              value={name}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className='signup__form__group'>
            <input
              className='signup__form__input'
              type='email'
              placeholder='Email *'
              name='email'
              value={email}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className='signup__form__group__password'>
            <input
              className='signup__form__input'
              type='password'
              placeholder='Password *'
              name='password'
              value={password}
              onChange={e => {onChange(e); setStrongpassword(e.target.value)}}
              minLength='8'
              required
            />
          </div>
          <PasswordStrengthMeter strongpassword={strongpassword} />
          <div className='signup__form__group'>
            <input
              className='signup__form__input'
              type='password'
              placeholder='Confirm Password *'
              name='re_password'
              value={re_password}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              minLength='8'
              required
            />
          </div>
          <Button className='signup__button__main' type='submit'>Register</Button>
        </form>
        <p className='signup__authtext'>
          Already have an account? <Link to='/login' className='signup__link'>Login</Link>
        </p>
        
      </div>
      <WelcomePageFooter/>
    </div>
  )
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { setAlert, signup }) (Signup);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you know how to use JavaScript's Regex APIs. You can't simply compare a Regex with a string, it'll always be inequal. Instead of `password !== pattern` try `!pattern.test(password)`.

Comment: I don't like your password policy. Setting a minimum of 8 characters is okay I guess, but demanding a mixture of mixed case alphabet characters, digits, symbols from `@$*?&` and **nothing else** is going to cause annoyance. If you reject [perfectly safe passwords](https://www.security.org/how-secure-is-my-password/) like `wing interest eleven level`users will probably end up choosing the shortest password that gets accepted by your system, like `P@ssw0rd` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding pattern in input as bellow ;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { signup } from '../actions/auth';
import './Signup.css';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { setAlert } from '../actions/alert';
import PasswordStrengthMeter from '../components/PasswordStrengthMeter';
import WelcomePageFooter from '../components/WelcomePageFooter';

function Signup({setAlert, signup, isAuthenticated }) {

  const [ strongpassword, setStrongpassword ] = useState('s');

  const [accountCreated, setAccountCreated] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    re_password: ''
  });

  const { name, email, password, re_password } = formData;
  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (password !== re_password)
            setAlert('Passwords do not match', 'error');

    if (password === re_password) {
      signup (name, email, password, re_password);
      setAccountCreated(true);
    }
  };
 
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to='/' />
  }
  if (accountCreated) {
    return <Navigate to='/login' />
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='login'>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Diploman - Sign Up</title>
          <meta 
            name='description'
            content='sign up page'
          />
        </Helmet>
        <h1 className='signup__title'>Sign Up</h1>
        <p className='signup__lead'>Create your Account</p>
        <form className='signup__form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <div className='signup__form__group'>
            <input
              className='signup__form__input'
              type='text'
              placeholder='Name *'
              name='name'
              value={name}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className='signup__form__group'>
            <input
              className='signup__form__input'
              type='email'
              placeholder='Email *'
              name='email'
              value={email}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className='signup__form__group__password'>
            <input
              className='signup__form__input'
              type='password'
              placeholder='Password *'
              name='password'
              value={password}
              onChange={e => {onChange(e); setStrongpassword(e.target.value)}}
              minLength='8'
              pattern='((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@@#$%&?])(?!.*[;]).{8,32})'
              required
            />
          </div>
          <PasswordStrengthMeter strongpassword={strongpassword} />
          <div className='signup__form__group'>
            <input
              className='signup__form__input'
              type='password'
              placeholder='Confirm Password *'
              name='re_password'
              value={re_password}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              minLength='8'
              pattern='((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@@#$%&?])(?!.*[;]).{8,32})'
              required
            />
          </div>
          <Button className='signup__button__main' type='submit'>Register</Button>
        </form>
        <p className='signup__authtext'>
          Already have an account? <Link to='/login' className='signup__link'>Login</Link>
        </p>
        
      </div>
      <WelcomePageFooter/>
    </div>
  )
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { setAlert, signup }) (Signup);
```